# A finite alternate binomial sum with finite value (modulo 6)

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

We use Iverson symbol ( [expr] is $1$ when expr is true else $0$), and $n\%6$ for $n$ modulo $6$. .

For any $n >= 2 $.

Let $ F(n) := \sum_{j>=1} (-1)^j {\binom {n-j-2} j } $

Prove that $F(n) = [n\%6 \in \{0,5\}] - [n\%6 \in \{2,3\}]$

In other words:

IF   $n$ modulo $6$ is $0$ or $5$    then $F(n) = 1$

IF  $n$ modulo $6$ is $2$ or $3$ then $F(n) =-1$

IF  $n$ modulo $6$ is $1$ or $4$ then $F(n) =0$

It is true up to $n=15$ by hand, $40$ would be safe

Yet to what kind of identities does this belong? .And how to prove this?

Can we replace  $-2$ by another constant and still have the same behaviour ( finite set of value with periodic recurrence.

**Note** : The motivation is to calculate

$ F(n) = \sum (-1)^k[a_1a_2a_3 \dots a_k=2^n] $. Where any $a_i$ is >= 3.

Comment: generating functions?

Comment: This is essentially Corollary 7.63 in [Darij Grinberg, *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*, Version of 26 April 2018](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2018-04-26). (Well, my sum begins at $j = 0$, not at $j = 1$, and I use $n$ instead of $n-2$, but this boils down to subtracting a $1$ and substituting $n-2$ for $n$.) It's a fairly known result.

Comment: Corollary 7.63, not Section 7.63. The corollary is on page 507, and relies on pages 500--507.

Comment: OK thank you so much, this is much better with reference your page 120 and then to LeeSchi cluster algebra ... . 
I saw you are not yet an aficionados of Iverson Bracket, please check the one line note added at the end of the question which I hope will convince you of its many virtues.

Answer (score 1):

Working with the following sum

$$\sum_{q=0}^n (-1)^q {n-q\choose q}$$

we have

$$\sum_{q=0}^n (-1)^q {n-q\choose n-2q}
= \sum_{q=0}^n (-1)^q [z^{n-2q}] (1+z)^{n-q}
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^n \sum_{q=0}^n (-1)^q z^{2q} (1+z)^{-q}.$$

Now we get zero contribution when $2q\gt n$ hence we may write

$$[z^n] (1+z)^n \sum_{q\ge 0} (-1)^q z^{2q} (1+z)^{-q}
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^n \frac{1}{1+z^2/(1+z)}
= [z^n] (1+z)^{n+1} \frac{1}{1+z+z^2}.$$

This is

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=0}
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}} (1+z)^{n+1} \frac{1}{1+z+z^2}.$$

With the substitution $z/(1+z)=w$ or $z=w/(1-w)$ we have
$dz = 1/(1-w)^2 \; dw$ and we obtain

$$\mathrm{Res}_{w=0}
\frac{1}{w^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{1+w/(1-w)+w^2/(1-w)^2}  \frac{1}{(1-w)^2}
\\ = \mathrm{Res}_{w=0}
\frac{1}{w^{n+1}}  \frac{1}{(1-w)^2+w(1-w)+w^2}
\\ = \mathrm{Res}_{w=0}
\frac{1}{w^{n+1}}  \frac{1}{1-w+w^2}
= [w^n]  \frac{1}{1-w+w^2}.$$

Starting from

$$G(w) = \frac{1}{1-w+w^2}$$

we have $$(1-w+w^2) G(w) = 1$$

so that

$$[w^0] (1-w+w^2) G(w) = G_0 = [w^0] 1 = 1$$

and furthermore

$$[w^1] (1-w+w^2) G(w) = G_1-G_0 = [w^1] 1 = 0$$

This establishes the initial values $G_0=1$ and $G_1=1.$

Moreover for $n\ge 2$ we find

$$[w^n] (1-w+w^2) G(w) = G_n - G_{n-1} + G_{n-2}
= [w^n] 1 = 0$$

producing the recurrence

$$G_n = G_{n-1} - G_{n-2}.$$

This means  $G_n$ only depends  on the preceding two  values. Starting
from $1,1$ we obtain by applying the recurrence

$$1,1,0,-1,-1,0,1,1,\ldots$$

We have  reached the  period (intial pair  appears), thus  proving the
claim.

We may also compute the generating function by snake oil method.
Start with

$$G(w) = \sum_{n\ge 0} w^n \sum_{q=0}^n (-1)^q {n-q\choose q}
= \sum_{q\ge 0} (-1)^q \sum_{n\ge q} w^n {n-q\choose q}
\\ = \sum_{q\ge 0} (-1)^q w^q \sum_{n\ge 0} w^n {n\choose q}
= \sum_{q\ge 0} (-1)^q w^q \sum_{n\ge q} w^n {n\choose q}
\\ = \sum_{q\ge 0} (-1)^q w^{2q} \sum_{n\ge 0} w^n {n+q\choose q}
= \sum_{q\ge 0} (-1)^q w^{2q} \frac{1}{(1-w)^{q+1}}  
\\ = \frac{1}{1-w} \frac{1}{1+w^2/(1-w)}
= \frac{1}{1-w+w^2}.$$

Comment: Very good , the snake oil version is pretty clear. Yet the reason for a period is not so clear. Say if we have say $n-\lambda q$ instead of $n-q$ in the binomial  do we have a period?